# Correct axes to use dot product to evaluate the final output of a listwise learning to rank model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, numpy-ndarray

I'm not being able to find the correct configuration to pass to a tf.keras.layers.Dot to make a pairwise dot product when the entries each have lists of values, like from a listwise learning to rank model. For instance, suppose:

```
repeated_query_vector = [
  [[1, 2], [1, 2]],
  [[3, 4], [3, 4]]
]

document_vectors = [
  [[5, 6], [7, 8]],
  [[9, 10], [11, 12]],
]
```

Calling tf.keras.layers.Dot(axes=??)([repeated_query_vector, document_vectors]) I want the output to be like:

```
[
  [1*5 + 2*6, 1*7 + 2*8]
  [3*9 + 4*10, 3*11 + 4*12]
]
```

All examples I found in the documentation have one dimension less than my use case. What would be the correct value of axes for this call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to solve this with `tf.keras.layers.Multiply()` and `tf.reshape`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

repeated_query_vector = tf.constant([
  [[1, 2], [1, 2]],
  [[3, 4], [3, 4]]
])

document_vectors = tf.constant([
  [[5, 6], [7, 8]],
  [[9, 10], [11, 12]],
])

multiply_layer = tf.keras.layers.Multiply()
result = multiply_layer([repeated_query_vector, document_vectors])
shape = tf.shape(result)
result = tf.reduce_sum(tf.reshape(result, (shape[0], shape[1] * shape[2])), axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[ 40]
 [148]], shape=(2, 1), dtype=int32)
```

Or with `tf.keras.layers.Dot` and `tf.reshape`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

repeated_query_vector = tf.constant([
  [[1, 2], [1, 2]],
  [[3, 4], [3, 4]]
])

document_vectors = tf.constant([
  [[5, 6], [7, 8]],
  [[9, 10], [11, 12]],
])

dot_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dot(axes=1)
result = dot_layer([tf.reshape(repeated_query_vector, (repeated_query_vector.shape[0], repeated_query_vector.shape[1] * repeated_query_vector.shape[2])),
                         tf.reshape(document_vectors, (document_vectors.shape[0], document_vectors.shape[1] * document_vectors.shape[2]))])
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[ 40]
 [148]], shape=(2, 1), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: It works without the tf.reshape inside the tf.reduce_sum for the first example, thanks!. Notice I had a comma between [1*5 + 2*6, 1*7 + 2*8] on the example array. Editing this out I can accept this answer!

Comment: So the solution works for you? Without tf.reshape it is working right ?

Comment: Yes! Thank you.